# Solving a system of real-valued polynomials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

How would i solve this system of equations

$(x+y+z)^2 - 4 - 5yz = 0$

$(x+y+z)^2 - 4 - 5xz = 0$

$(x+y+z)^2 - 4 - 5xy = 0$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: Subtract any two of the equations: $z(x-y) = 0 = y(x-z) = x(y-z)$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

In general, solving systems of polynomials is a very hard problem—so hard that two whole fields, [algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry) and [commutative algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_algebra), have grown up around it. If you want to solve an arbitrary system of polynomials, you're probably going to need heavy-duty tools like [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis).

Your system of polynomials, however, is far from arbitrary. For one thing, the expression $(x + y + z)^2 - 4$ appears in every equation! When an expression shows up several times, it's often useful to make up a name for it, so try creating a new variable $t = (x + y + z)^2 - 4$ and substituting it into all the equations. This may help you see what to do next.

(This hint is actually the same as [A1DHTH's hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1466671/16063), but from a different point of view.)